# Reading/Writing integer values on a string object

Tags: c++

I have the contents of a file assigned into a string object. For simplicity the file only has 5 bytes, which is the size of 1 integer plus another byte.
What I want to do is get the first four bytes of the string object and somehow store it into a valid integer variable by the program.
Then the program will do various operations on the integer, changing it.
Afterward I want the changed integer stored back into the first four bytes of the string object.

Could anyone tell me I could achieve this? I would prefer to stick with the standard C++ library exclusively for this purpose. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I haven't even taken a programming class before. Thanks to all replies relevant to the problem.

Comment: Oh, I just saw this: Do you mean the integer is stored _binary_? Then my answer is nonsense. I'll delete it.

Comment: I honestly couldn't say. I want the integer to store it in to be a regular integer, the kind you would get if you declared it like "int i;" Then I could add, subtract, etc. the variable i.

Comment: Well, if you cannot even say whether the integer is stored binary or ASCII, how do you want to read and write it?

Comment: Oh. In the file, the integer is stored in binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet should illustrate a handful of things. Beware of endian differences. Play around with it. Try to understand what's going on. Add some file operations (binary read & write). The only way to really understand how to do this, is to experiment and create some tests.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 108554107; // some random number for example sake

    char c[4];            // simulate std::string containing a binary int
    *((int *) &c[0]) = a; // use casting to copy the data

    // reassemble a into b, using indexed bytes from c
    int b = 0;
    b |= (c[3] & 0xff) << 24;
    b |= (c[2] & 0xff) << 16;
    b |= (c[1] & 0xff) << 8;
    b |= c[0] & 0xff;

    // show that all three are equivalent
    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b
        << " c: " << *((int *) &c[0]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. *((int *) &c) is working exactly how I want it to convert a char sequence to an integer.

Comment: Please note that casting any memory address to larger types may give you cpu alignment faults.  It's ok on x86 processesors because they allow you to do it, but pretty much all other processors will generate a alignment fault.  If you want your code to be cross-platform you can use memcpy instead of *(int*).  e.g. int i; memcpy(&i, c, sizeof(i));

Comment: Thanks for the info, I just got it to work with memcpy as well. I'll use that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading into `std::string` from that file any zero byte would signal end of the string, so you might end up with a string that is shorter then 5 bytes. Take a look [here](http://www.angelfire.com/country/aldev0/cpphowto/cpp_BinaryFileIO.html) for how to do **binary I/O** with C++ streams.

Comment: I can verify that the string object I am working with is the correct size as the file, even with a zero byte in it. On the site you linked, on the section about reading data it uses myFile.read (buffer, 100); with myFile being an ifstream object and buffer being a char array. I want to read the first four bytes as a regular int variable, not a char array.

Comment: Get further to "Reading/writing non-character data". Just read into your int, without intermediate string.